# Different solution platforms activates same post build events

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created 64 bit platform for my DLL project in Visual Studio C++ project. I have edited post build events that must copy binary to particular folder. I found that even I build with 64 bit setup system calls 32 bit setup post build scripts.

Why? How to solve that?